# Why did the trolls go into hiding on stepwise worlds?

Tags: the-long-earth

During the events of the Second book of the Long Earth Series - the Long War - the trolls stopped singing, and went into hiding on stepwise worlds?

The text inside the cover of the book implies that they're moving away from the worlds that humans are inhabiting.

> And the trolls - those graceful hive-mind humanoids whose songs once
> suffused the Long Earth - are, in the face of man's inexorable
> advance, beginning to fall silent ... and to disappear

Yet the contents of the books, and other books in the series, show that trolls regularly live in human colonies and don't seem to have any great fear of humans, and them going to ground isn't mentioned again in the three subsequent books.

Later books such as The Long Cosmos has trolls being an in universe metaphor for migrant laborers, or living with humans in nomadic groups.

Comment: I have spent the majority of my life living around humans and I can honestly say that if there was a viable alternative, I'd take it.

Comment: Is that a quote from one of the books?

Comment: No. I am speaking from personal experience